# Android - Turn screen back to off mode

Tags: java, android, lockscreen, android-windowmanager

I was looking to implement a whatsapp like pop-up in my project and i succesfully implemeted it by using 'Dialogue as Activity'. Below code is the one which helps to turn on the screen and show the pop-up while the phone is in sleep mode.

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
);
```

but it keep staying in the "screen on" mode after that. I couldn't find any method for "turning screen off".

Do anybody know a way to solve this issue ?

Comment: Maybe the settings on the device itself is what is keeping it on? Like if the settings were to keep screen lit for a long time after a notification

Comment: i appreciate your effort to help, but it is not the situation here. i need it to be similar like a pop-up in whatsapp, i suceeded in implementing and popping it up when the screen is turned off, but after that screen is not turning off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you no more need to keep the screen on, simply remove the flags that keep your screen on

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Thanks brother, Hope it will help others too.